# Gitignore: double exception

Tags: git, exception, gitignore

I wonder how I can implement a double exception in a gitignore file. As an example: I want it to ingore every file, except .ktr files, except some specific ktr files.

Please see the following example:

```
/.project
#Ignore every file
*

#Except these file extensions
!*.gitignore
!*.sh
!*.ktr

#However, do ignore the following files
SomeFolder/**/GetJson.ktr
SomeFolder/**/GetToken.ktr
build/
```

The problem is when I do

```
$git status
```

It shows

```
deleted: all ktr files, including some files that were supposed to be ignored
```

It isn't supposted to mark all files as deleted nor mark files that should be ignored.

How can I make it ignore every file, except files with a certain extension but do make it ignore some specific files with the extension that I don't want to ignore.